# Are there any pure Python, BSD-ish open source SVG libraries?

Tags: python, svg

I'm looking for a pure Python library to help put together SVG images.  It doesn't need to be fast.

I know [pySVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/) exists, but I'm not interested in a GPL library (and I can't use GPL libraries for this particular project).

Basic SVG elements aren't especially complicated, so I suppose I could roll my own, but I'd rather participate in an existing project than go off on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a library that I use to generate XHTML and SVG and I posted it [here](http://carrickbender.com/XMLlib.tgz).  It's pretty easy, each element has a corresponding all upper case class, the __init__ parameters are child elements and keyword parameters are attributes.  The **Transformable** class, inherited by **PATH** and **RECT**, have additional functions for building attribute values.

Have fun with it, I'm posting this as free to use for anything you want, and if you make some improvements I would appreciate them.  If there's more interest I'll make it a SourceForge or Google Code project.

[edit: remove the import of the DebugContents class and the _debugContents attribute in XML.py, that's part of a large debugging framework.]

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thanks!  Now, would you be willing to put together a project page which lists the license and link to that page, rather than linking directly to a binary with no license information?

Answer (score 1):

If your backend is OpenGL, I recommend [Squirtle-SVG-Library](http://www.supereffective.org/pages/Squirtle-SVG-Library) that draws SVG images using pyglet.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have a pyglet dependency, but I agree that this satisfies my requirements, thanks!